# A System of Matrix Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, matrix-equations

I am looking for the solutions to the following system of matrix equations:

(1)  $AA^{*} - A^{*}A = C^{*}C - BB^{*}$

(2)  $DD^{*} - D^{*}D = B^{*}B - CC^{*}$

(3)  $AC^{*} - C^{*}D = A^{*}B - BD^{*}$

where $A, B, C, D \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$

I have found some trivial and non-trivial solutions but not the kind that I am hoping to find.
In particular, does there exist a family of solutions $(A_n, B_n, C_n, D_n)$ such that the operator norm of $B_n$ and $C_n$ are "different."

Comment: You may be aware of this already, but this system of "matrix" equations is really just a system of linear equations, written in an unusual way.